# template specialization with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have started learning c++ recently. And I sometimes confused with template specialization. Could someone tell me the reason why the following template specialization at No(3) is illegal?

```
template<typename T>  // No (1)
class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA();
    virtual ~ClassA();

    void func(void);
};

template<>  // No (2)
void ClassA<int>::func(void) {}   // Ok legal specialization

template<typename T>  // No (3)
void ClassA<int>::func(void) {}   // error by compiler
```

It seems Template specialization at No (3) has no implicit template parameter because typename T is int. But compiler give the following error,

```
error: prototype for ‘void ClassA<int>::func()’ does not match any in class ‘ClassA<int>’ void ClassA<int>::func(void) {
                           ^

error: candidate is: void ClassA<T>::func() [with T = int] void func(void);
                          ^
```

I am afraid I am asking a stupid question but I really want to know the reason of error. And I wonder typename Ts at No 1 and No3 are same or not. Please tell me them. Thank you very much.

Comment: neither (2) nor (3) should compile

Comment: In C++ you would normally write `func()` rather than `func(void)`. The later is only allowed for backward compatibility with C.

Answer (score 2):

(2) is the way to write specialization.

`T` in (1) and (3) are not really the same, you may write (for non specialization):

```
template <typename U>
void ClassA<U>::func(void) {}
```

whereas it was `T` in (1)

or partial specialize

```
template <typename T>
void ClassA<std::vector<T>>::func(void) {}
```

where here the `T1` in (1) would be `std::vector<T3>`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jarod42. It is what I wanted to know. But if so, I wonder why we cannot write just void ClassA<int>::func(void) {} inspite of template<> void ClassA<int>::func(void) {}? I feels the first template<> is confused me.

Comment: I think it is to have a single syntax and coherent syntax (with N or even 0 template argument). Note also that grammar has to manage template method for template class (`template <T> template <U> void A<T>::foo(U)`) and explicit instantiation (`template class A<int>;`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
template<typename T>
void ClassA<int>::func(void) {}
```

Use

```
template<typename T>
void ClassA<T>::func(void) {}
        // ^^^ T, not it.
```

I am not sure whether the use of `int` was on purpose or it was an oversight.

Comment: Their question appears to be about declaring the `<int>` specialization of their template, not the general template definition.

Comment: Hi and think you for answering it, coryKramer. It was on purpose. I intened the template parameter at No (1) as int but I also intentionally put the typename T at No(3) because I supposed the T at No(3) is deduced to int.